# Product Detail pages cms block

Tags: event-observer

possible display Product Detail in different page?
i want add new page and add display product with button checkout/add to cart, quanity with dynamic price changes how this: http://sarp2.demo.aheadworks.com/authorize/index.php/subscriptions/coffee.html, possible to implement this without an Observer, i have link: http://demo.local/subscriptions/ - here need display page product details.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm somewhat confused. Do you want to display dynamic product information (price, name, image, etc.) on CMS page? If yes, then you should look into Magento feature called widgets. More information about widgets can be found here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/introducing-magento-widgets/

There's number of commercial widgets available as well, but since this site policy is not to promote third parties you have to google them yourself.

PS. Since demo.local is your local server, it's not available for the rest of us.

Comment: thanks, but i can add in widget custom options with quantity and dynamic price change?

Comment: I recommend to search around for widgets. I'm pretty sure that there's an existing commercial widget that can display quantities and price ranges.